# Convert sting in datetime like excel format cell does in t-sql

Tags: excel, t-sql, date

I have END_Date data like 43830.99931. When I paste it in the excel and format the cell to Date. It convert it to 12/31/2019  11:59:00 PM. I want same functionality in T-SQL. How can I achieve same result using T-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel (by default) uses the 1900 date system. This simply means that the date 1 Jan 1900 has a true numeric value of 1, 2 Jan 1900 has a value of 2 etc. These values are called "serial values" in Excel and it is these serial values that allows us to use dates in calculations.

The code to convert:

```
DECLARE @SerialDate FLOAT;
SET @SerialDate = 43830.99931;
SELECT CAST(@SerialDate - 2 AS DATETIME);
```

returning back the date time value of:

```
2019-12-31 23:59:00.383
```

You may have noticed the `-2` in the cast. That's because Excel, due to issues with 29th Feb 1900 and the inclusiveness of the start/end dates. (1900-01-01 is day 1 not day 0, and 1900 was not a leap year but excel calculates it wrongly) we have to subtract 2.  Details on that issue can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year).